# How to get href from an a tag inside a div

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup, some how I cannot extract href inside the a tags, no matter what I do it returns errors to me. here is the function I am using

```
def scrape_a(url):
  r = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
  news =  soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "news"})
  return news
```

the html data structure is

```
<div class="news">
<a href="www.link.com">
<h2 class="heading">
Kenyan police foil potential bomb attack in Nairobi mall 
</h2>
<div class="teaserImg">
<img alt="" border="0" height="124" src="/image">
</div>
<p> text </p>
</a>
</div>
```

What I want to extract from these is href and h2 class='heading', whenever I try to get the both I get an error none type object has no attribute get item

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_news_class_hrefs(html):
    """
    Finds all urls pointed to by all links inside
    'news' class div elements
    """
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    links = [a['href'] for div in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "news"}) for a in div.find_all('a')]
    return links

# example html copied from question
html="""<div class="news">
<a href="www.link.com">
<h2 class="heading">
Kenyan police foil potential bomb attack in Nairobi mall 
</h2>
<div class="teaserImg">
<img alt="" border="0" height="124" src="/image">
</div>
<p> text </p>
</a>"""

get_news_class_hrefs(html)
# Output:
# [u'www.link.com']
```

Comment: returns error: return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'href'

Comment: hmm... can't reproduce that issue? What are you running exactly? I'll update to show the full code I'm running.

Comment: Oh if you are using BeautifulSoup<=3.x.x, you need to use `BeautifulSoup(html)`  and use `findAll` instead of `find_all` -- `soup.find_all()` will always return `None` in older versions